# tkinter - Basic Login Form checking from csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter login form, the program is supposed to allow existing users to type their username in a entry box and their password in an entry box, python then needs to read the values stored on a csv file and then check whether both the username and password are correct, they then use the submit button which will check if the credentials are right and if they are; it will allow them to go to the next frame. I'm not sure how to make it work properly because the submit button doesn't do anything.

Here is my code:

```
class MainMenu(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = tk.Label(self, text="     Main Menu - Login    ", fg="red", font=controller.title_font2)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)
    usernameL = tk.Label(self, text="Username").pack(side="top") 
    uUserLogin = tk.Entry(self)
    uUserLogin.pack()
    passwordL = tk.Label(self, text="Password").pack(side="top")
    uUserPassword = tk.Entry(self)
    uUserPassword.pack()

    def checkUser():
        uLoginUser = False
        uLoginPassword = False
        uUserCheck = uUserLogin.get()
        uUserCheckP = uUserPassword.get()
        with open("Users.csv", "r") as f:
            csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
            for row in csvreader:
                if uUserCheck == row[0]:
                    uLoginUser == True
                    if uUserCheckP == row[1]:
                        uLoginPassword == True
                        #labelT = tk.Label(self, text="Hello")
                        #labelT.pack()
        if uLoginUser and uLoginPassword == True:
            controller.show_frame("MainTMenu")

    submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                       command=checkUser())
    submit.pack()


    #If correct -> Go to next frame
```

The csv file is laid out with the first row being 2 headers - first column saying "Users" and the second column saying "Passwords" - the rest of the rows include the users and passwords in the correct columns and the right rows.

This might help for understanding the format (in case i explained it badly):

```
 Users, Passwords
 user, password
 user, password
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> The submit button doesn't do anything

This can be fixed easily, the problem is that your function init creates the button it calls the command rather than storing it `command=checkUser()`, there are two ways to fix this.

Change the command option of the button to `command=checkUser`, or `command=lambda: checkUser()`

> To fix the way your login form works I changed the checkUser() function, here is my update

```py
def checkUser():
    uUserCheck = uUserLogin.get()
    uUserCheckP = uUserPassword.get()
    with open("Users.csv", "r") as f:
        csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        for row in csvreader:
            if uUserCheck == row[0] and uUserCheckP == row[1]:
                labelT = tk.Label(self, text="Hello")
                labelT.pack()
                controller.show_frame("MainTMenu")
                break
```

This removes the use of nested if statements, and will terminate the for loop if a match of username and password is found, so then it doesn't have to check every username and password option every time.

If you have any other questions feel free to ask :)